# VSTO Outlook: HOWTO add a manifest file app.manifest

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, manifest, office-addins

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in which uses some WPF components. I have some problems on WPF components to be rendered correctly. For example, some objects are shown more bigger,  etc. I have found a possible solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58679375/1624552) when you mix winform and wpf components. May I guess VSTO Outlook addin in fact are winforms? So I need to specify some configuration in an app.manifest file and I do not know how to create the manifest file. I don't know if the process to create it is the same as a normal winforms app or in case of an Outlook VSTO Add-in is different.

In the link I provided above it is explained to add some setting in the assemblyinfo.cs file, ok there is no problem with it, i have done it, but now I do not know how to add some settings to the app.manifest file. I have seen in the \bin\release folder I have an myAddin.dll.manifest but this file is created automatically when you build the Add-in so i guess i cannot touch it because if so it will be overwritten again when I do a new build/rebuild of my add-in. Also the content within myAddin.dll.manifest, from where is taken?

Please could you indicate me the steps i must follow?

UPDATE:
This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/application-and-deployment-manifests-in-office-solutions?view=vs-2022) says application manifest file is created automatically, as I was guessing.

> Application manifests are created automatically as part of the build
> process.

So is there any way to create a post-build action to add a custom setting to application manifest?

One possibility would be to modify the manifest MyAddin.dll.manifest after build process suceed but i would like to automate it. Also i am wondering if there is the possibility to create an additional manifest file and Visual Studio merge it with the default one during the building process.

Answer (score 2):

VSTO add-ins are not standalone applications like Windows Forms. The manifest file is created per-application, not add-in. So, the best what you could do is to create a manifest file for the host application which is Outlook in your case. The manifest file should be named in the following way:

```
Outlook.exe.manifest
```

and should be placed to the same folder with Outlook.exe application.

So, if you need to make changes with a manifest file they will be applied to the whole host application (Outlook) and have impact on all add-ins, not only yours.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest works on the application level (exe), but VSTO addins are dlls hosted by outlook.exe, and you cannot add or update its manifest.